# Integrate my app installed by azure draft to Istio

Tags: istio

How should i do to make my app installed by [azure/draft](https://github.com/azure/draft) integrate with Istio?

Specifically, on official Istio documentation:

https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start.html

> If you do not have the Istio-Initializer installed, you must use istioctl kube-inject to manuallly inject Envoy containers in your application pods before deploying them:
>
> kubectl create -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f .yaml)

What / where should I modify the Helm chart folder that created by azure/draft to work with Istio?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not specific to Azure.

There are two ways to integrate Istio with an app:

1.Deploy the Istio initializer before deploying your app. (undeploy it, deploy the initializer and then deploy your app again). Run `kubectl create -f install/kubernetes/istio-initializer.yaml`. After that moment, all the deployed kubernetes pods in the future in the cluster will be integrated with Istio.

2.Integrate Istio with particular apps, not with every app. For those apps to be integrated with Istio, instead of running: `kubectl create -f app.yaml` as you would normally do, run `kubectl create -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f .yaml)`.

Comment: Actually my `azure/draft` != Azure. It's a sort of next generation of Deis Workflow. Have updated my question with link. Please take a look.

Comment: I see, so my answer will not help you. Your question is about modifying the Helm Charts generated by the framework. I have only basic familiarity with Helm Charts. My two cents on it: You can use https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/incubator/istio to install Istio itself, including Istio initializer. Or you can try to modify the generated template of your app, by running `istioctl kube-inject` on it and replacing its contents with the output of `istioctl kube-inject`.